# integral $I=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\alpha x^{2k}}dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

$$
I=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\alpha x^{2k}} dx
$$
The last problem was ill posed, and is answered in the post!
You can disregard this post!

Comment: Look at the original integral, and consider what would happen if $\beta$ were negative.  You should be able to see why the power series in $\beta$ *must* have zero radius of convergence around $\beta=0$.

Comment: $\beta >0$ @mjqxxxx

Comment: I know; but the power series can only converge if the function is analytic in some neighborhood of $\beta=0$ in the complex plane.  It clearly isn't… presumably it has a branch cut at the origin.

Comment: @mjqxxxx Okay I see thanks

Comment: According to Gradshteyn and Ryzhik, the following is true (which you can relate directly to your case:

$$\int_0^{\infty} \exp(-\beta^2x^4-2\gamma^2x^2)\,dx = \frac{\gamma}{2^{\frac{3}{2}}\beta}e^{\frac{\gamma^4}{2\beta^2}}K_{\frac{1}{4}} \left(\frac{\gamma^4}{2\beta^2} \right ),$$

where $K_{\frac{1}{4}}$ is the Bessel function of the second kind.

Comment: @CameronWilliam can you format that please, thanks!

Comment: @Integrals Yeah I'm trying but it's not rendering for whatever reason. Maybe comments have limited rendering ability. I'm not sure.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Ok Thank you, I saw this from numerics too, I guess i can't use a series representation

Comment: @Integrals Actually this is a very peculiar bug. It would not render K_{\frac{1}{4}}\left(\frac{\gamma^4}{2\beta^2}\right) but it would render K_{\frac{1}{4}} \left(\frac{\gamma^4}{2\beta^2}\right) (where I have inserted a space before \left).

Comment: Is the purpose of this question to evaluate the integral using power series technique?

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal yes exactly, series in terms of $\beta$.  Thanks

Comment: @CameronWilliams interesting

Comment: I've thrown it to MSE Meta. Let's see what others think on this matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Any ideas what's going wrong here?*

Yes. $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^{2k}}dx$ cannot be computed by expanding $e^t$ into its Taylor series, and then switching the order of summation and integration. It just doesn't work. All you get is an alternating sum of $\pm\infty$, which is undetermined.

Comment: Oh, Clear answer!  thank you very.  However, I am looking for a power series representation to this answer?  Is that possible?

Comment: I honestly don't know.

Comment: if nobody posts a power series representation in powers of $\beta$ I will check you as the correct answer

Comment: In theory it can be.  But to justify switching the order of integration and summation, you would need to evaluate $\int_{-N}^{0} e^{-x^{2k}} \ dx + \int_{0}^{N} e^{-x^{2k}} \ dx$ and then take the limit.